# RunTimeValueProvider not being accepted during Batch Dataflow Job run from Google Workspace API

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am submitting a Dataflow batch job using the Google Workspace API. This dataflow job does data processing from multiple BQ tables. I am attempted to make one of the queries that is submitted to BQ a RuntimeValueProivder argument.

```
def run():
    ARGS = ['--option=option,...']
    
    class MyPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):
            @classmethod
            def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
                parser.add_value_provider_argument(
                '--query',
                type=str,
                help='query for bq')
        
        pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(ARGS)
        p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
        custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(MyPipelineOptions) 
        
        pcol = (
            p | 'runtime_value_provider_query' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(query=custom_options.query, 
                                                                           use_standard_sql=True)
              ...
```

```
def run_dataflow():
    
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(cred_file)

    service = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', credentials=credentials)
    gcp_project = "gcp_project"
    template_path = "gs://template_path"
    template_body = {
        "jobName": "dataflow-job",
        "parameters": {
            "query": create_query() #this is a function that returns a query string
            },
        "environment": {}
        }

    request = service.projects().templates().launch(projectId=gcp_project, gcsPath=template_path, body=template_body)
    response = request.execute()
```

From what I can see way I structure the argument is correct, although when I create the template and run a job with the correct submission parameters all that is seen in the query is RuntimeValueProvider(option=query, type: stre, defualt_value=None). Rather than the parameter I submitted, which is listed correctly in the Pipeline options area of the Job info.

I have read the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.23.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html) to see that ReadFromBigQuery should accept ValueProvider as a valid type under the query argument.

I am open to a different pipelines structure as I am new to Apache beam.

This is also my first time asking a question on SO, so any advice for formatting my question is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) instead.

Comment: I did see that as a suggestion somewhere else, I guess I am still confused at why the functionality that was documented does not want to work correctly.

Comment: As to that, I'm not sure. There have been many iterations of ReadFromBigquery; my guess is that something broke or the documentation got out of sync.